# Adding NSArray to NSDictionary is causing problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm writing an app in XCode 3.2.3 for iOS 4. In my code, I am creating an NSArray of NSDictionaries, each containing two key/value pairs, a string and an NSArray of NSDictionaries (kind of confusing, I know). Just to give you a visual, here is the structure:

```
<NSArray>
    <NSDictionary>
        <NSString/>
        <NSArray>
            <NSDictionary/>
            <NSDictionary/>
            ...
        </NSArray>
    </NSDictionary>
    ...
</NSArray>
```

What's weird is that when I add a new NSDictionary to the innermost NSArray, it seems to add the same dictionary to the NSArray contained within *each* of the outer NSDictionaries. Here's how I'm adding the innermost NSDictionary to the innermost NSArray:

```
[[outerDict objectForKey:@"innerArray"] addObject:innerDict];
```

So, just to recap, the output I want is something like this:

```
<outerArray>

    <outerDict1>
        <string>
        <innerArray1>
            <innerDict1>
            <innerDict2>
        </innerArray1>
    </outerDict1>

    <outerDict2>
        <string>
        <innerArray2>
            <innerDict3>
            <innerDict4>
        </innerArray2>
    </outerDict2>

<outerArray>
```

But what I'm actually getting is this:

```
<outerArray>

    <outerDict1>
        <string>
        <innerArray1>
            <innerDict1>
            <innerDict2>
            <innerDict3>
            <innerDict4>
        </innerArray1>
    </outerDict1>

    <outerDict2>
        <string>
        <innerArray2>
            <innerDict1>
            <innerDict2>
            <innerDict3>
            <innerDict4>
        </innerArray2>
    </outerDict2>

<outerArray>
```

Notice that the inner NSDictionaries are added to **every** innerArray. For the life of me I can't figure out why!!

Any help would be very greatly appreciated, thank you!

-Matt

Comment: Could you post the code that creates this whole outerArray? `[[outerDict objectForKey:@"innerArray"] addObject:innerDict];` looks correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to post more code.

```
[[outerDict objectForKey:@"innerArray"] addObject:innerDict];
```

adds `innerDict` only to `innerArray` in `outerDict`, nothing else.

**That said**, you might have put the same `innerArray` twice into two different `outerDict`, like this:

```
NSMutableArray* innerArray=[NSMutableArray array];

[outerDict1 setObject:innerArray forKey:@"innerArray"];
[outerDict2 setObject:innerArray forKey:@"innerArray"];
```

This adds the **same** `innerArray` twice, not two independent arrays. Then, if you modify the `innerArray` in `outerDict1`, that will modify the `innerArray` in `outerDict2` too, because these two are the same arrays.

Comment: Wow thank you for the quick and accurate response! You were right, it was that I had added the same instance of the innerArray to each outerDict. Problem solved.